# Proof on positive sequence with $\limsup_{n} a_n^{1/n}=1$ and $\liminf_{n}a_n^{1/n} <1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does a positive sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $\limsup_{n} a_n^{1/n}=1$ and $\liminf_{n}a_n^{1/n} <1$ must have a subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ satisfying $\lim_{i} a_{n_i}^{1/n_i}=1$ and $\lim_{i} |a_{n_i}^2-a_{n_i-1}a_{n_i+1}|^{1/n_i}=1$.

So Here are the hypothesis:
\begin{equation} \limsup_{n} a_{n}^{1/n}=1 \tag1 \end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation} \liminf_{n} a_{n}^{1/n}<1 \tag2 \end{equation}
How to derive the conclusion: there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ fulfilling **both** of
\begin{equation} \lim_{i} a_{n_i}^{1/n_i}=1 \tag3 \end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} \lim_{i} |a_{n_i}^2-a_{n_i-1}a_{n_i+1}|^{1/n_i}=1 \tag4 \end{equation}

### My understanding to this problem

It is obvious that $(1)$ implies $(3)$, but how $(1)$ together with $(2)$ imply $(3)$ and $(4)$ is not so clear, although trivial examples such as
$$1,\delta^2,1,\delta^4,\cdots,1,\delta^{2n},\cdots$$
(where $0<\delta<1$) strongly support this proposition.

Given $(3)$ holds, $(4)$ may be replaced with the equivalent
\begin{equation}\lim_{i} \left|1-\frac{a_{n_i+1}}{a_{n_i}} \frac{a_{n_i-1}}{a_{n_i}}\right|^{1/n_i} =1 \end{equation}

So this suggests that $\dfrac{a_{n_i+1}}{a_{n_i}} \dfrac{a_{n_i-1}}{a_{n_i}}$ must be "small" enough. It seems somehow related to the ratio test vs the root test in convergence of series.

### What I expect

A proof (or a counter-example) is of course appreciated, but I also want to know the origin of this problem (in what literature did it emerge). Discussions giving an insight to this problem is welcomed as well.

Comment: I think your statement of the problem is unnecessarily complicated.  You could just as well have a sequence $b_n (=a_n^{\frac{1}{n}})$  with $\limsup_n b_n=1$ and $\liminf_n b_n\lt 1$.  Simple example $b_n=1$ for even $n$ and $b_n=0.5$ for odd $n$.

Comment: @herb-steinberg The essense of this problem lies in $(4)$. If we let $b_n=(a_n)^{1/n}~$, $~(4)$ would become $\lim_{i} |b_{n_i}^{2n_i}-b_{n_i-1}^{n_i -1}b_{n_i+1}^{n_i +1}|^{1/n_i}=1$, which seems just complicating the main point.

Comment: For even $n,\ |b_n^{2n}-b_{n-1}^{n-1}b_{n+1}^{n+1}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=|1-0.5^{2n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}\approx 1-\frac{1}{n}0.5^{2n}\to 1$.  Odd $n$ gives the same result.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you want to show.  You want a series where the limit is not 1?

Comment: How about a series where $b_n=1$, except when n is a multiple of 4 (or higher),where $b_n=0$?   Most of the time the terms in (4) will be $0$

Comment: @herb-steinberg OK, I have edited the problem to clarify. So if you mean $\{a_n\}=\{1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,\cdots\}$ (or the same as $\{bn\}$), Then $\{a_{4i−3}~\}$ (the ones just before each of the zero'es) is such a desired subsequence.

Comment: You are right.  I'll think some more about it.